# External Javascript file returning 404 error in django

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
<head>
    <!-- Include Google Maps JS API -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/?key=my-KEY&sensor=true">
```

Each time I call the view up the other html element show but the google map is not displayed. the console reveals a GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/?key=KEY&sensor=true 404 ()

PLS how will I load an external js in django?

Comment: Doesn't look like an error related django..

Comment: Close the script tag please.

Comment: The browser can't find it, because its not there. Open the link in `src` of the script tag in a new tab and you will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Django error in fact.

However, the solution is to switch to **`googleapis.com`**. Maps APIs should now be loaded from `maps.googleapis.com` rather than `maps.google.com` or `maps-api-ssl.google.com`.

## Edit

In fact, you are using `maps.googleapis.com`. This means that the error is caused by something else. I think that the problem is that your link is missing `js` after `?`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Static API is free and you can authenticate by API_KEY.
Google Maps Javascript (JS) API is not free any more and API_KEY authentication was disabled. For that reason you get 404 and 400 web response status.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start

> Reminder: To use the Maps JavaScript API:
> All Maps JavaScript API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access.
> You must enable billing on each of your projects.